# How to display gridLines in GridView from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

In aspx code i set `GridLines="None"`

How can i show GridLines from code behind when exporting grid-view to excel file.

```
protected void btnexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment;filename=UsersReport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gridusers.DataBind();
        gridusers.RenderControl(hw);
        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
}
```

Comment: gridusers.GridLines = 0;

Comment: The GridView renders as a table so wrap your GridView in a <div> with a class that sets the border of all contained <td> to 0   ... if want dynamically then apply this class from code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function start, set:

```
grdAdslCompanyAdvisers.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
```

after export again

```
grdAdslCompanyAdvisers.GridLines = GridLines.None;
```

Hope this helps or gives you an idea.